# Axes on image in IDL

Tags: graphics, axes, idl-programming-language

I have an image displayed in an IDL window using the TV command, and would like to add x and y axes to the image.  Seems straightforward, but I can't find a way to do it.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you tied to direct graphics, i.e., `TV`? Easiest way to display with axis is to use `IMAGE` function:

```
im = image(arr, axis_style=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm tied to version 6 of IDL, so I don't think I can use IMAGE function.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo Mike's answer - go with the new graphics Image function if possible.

If you absolutely have to use direct graphics, then I would recommend using David Fanning's coyote graphics wrappers:
http://www.idlcoyote.com/idldoc/cg/cgimage.html

It's still a lot more work to do this using direct graphics, but at least with the "cg" commands it's easier.

Comment: The version of IDL i'm using is on a university server, so I don't think I can install the Coyote library

Comment: You can install the coyote graphics programs in a subdirectory in your home directory and set your IDL path to point at it. For example, set the IDL_PATH environment variable to point at it with something like: export IDL_PATH=/home/me/idl/coyote:"<IDL_DEFAULT>"